# why do I get: Object [object Object] has no method in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to use the [jquery vertical ticker](http://www.jugbit.com/jquery-vticker-vertical-news-ticker/) I tried a test page which only contains the ticker and it works fine. But when I integrate it in the real page where I want to deploy it, it gives this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'vTicker' index.jsp:46
(anonymous function) index.jsp:46
jQuery.Callbacks.fire jquery-1.7.js:1064
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith jquery-1.7.js:1182
jQuery.extend.ready jquery-1.7.js:437
DOMContentLoaded
```

That's my code :

```
    <style type="text/css">

     #news-container
    {
        width: 400px; 
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 30px;
        border: 5px solid #333333;
    }

    #news-container ul li div
    {
       border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
       background: #ffffff;
     }
  </style>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/lib/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/lib/jquery.vticker.js">   </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 jQuery(function(){
jQuery('#news-container').vTicker({ 
    speed: 500,
    pause: 3000,
    animation: 'fade',
    mousePause: false,
    showItems: 3
});
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/lib/all-concat.js"/>
```

and this is the html div inside the body:

```
 <div id="news-container">
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, porta at, imperdiet id neque. more info
        </div>
    </li> 
    <li>
        <div>

            2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. more info
        </div>
    </li> 
    <li>
        <div>
            3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet more info more info more info more info
        </div>
    </li>   
    <li>
        <div>
            4) jugbit.com jquery vticker more info more info more info more info more info
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any idea why it's working in a separate page and not working here?

Comment: make sure your js file for vticker is loaded

Comment: As @robert said above, use firebug etc to see if the JS is being loaded correctly.

Comment: the javascript is loaded successfully

Comment: Either vticker.js is not loading, or its contents does not properly define a jQuery plugin, i.e. on the `jQuery.fn` namespace.

Comment: I edited the code , the last line `<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/lib/all-concat.js"/>` seems to be causing the problem.. I removed it and the ticker worked .. but other functionality stopped .. I need this script and the ticker as well working

Comment: @Utkanos the js file is loaded.. and this is the first line of it's content `(function($){
$.fn.vTicker = function(options) { ...` the complete content available from the link above. there is a conflict with another js file .. what would raise this error? where should I start looking to resolve the conflict..

Comment: @Sam: `script` tags cannot be self closed. It should be `<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/lib/all-concat.js"></script>`, but I don't know if that helps.

Comment: @FelixKling in fact when I do the closing tag for script, I get things screwed in the page! while with the self closing tag it's working fine !!! Re. the question, I put the last line (the script line) before including the jquery and vticker and the problem solved !! don't understand why and how though !!